# Material UI CSS Issue in Production

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am facing a bit weird issue with Material UI usage in my React application.

I am developing a server side rendered app and I have followed Material UI instruction for SSR implementation.

The issue is the app works fine on my Mac machine but when I build and run it on my Linux production server, its CSS goes crazy after 1 or 2 seconds on the first page load.

Now if I copy the **node_modules** and **build output** from my Mac machine to the server directly and not building it on Linux, it works fine. Same issue is happening on a Windows server.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You need to explain exactly what crazy means.

Comment: So it means that the page loads up correctly and then after 1 or 2 seconds, some of the styles fail. It seems to be inconsistency between the server-loaded and client-loaded stuff in the SSR React app but then why it happens only on the Linux machine?

Comment: This error appears on the server: Prop 'className' did not match. Server: 'jss77' Client: 'MuiSvgIcon-root-77'.